# In huffman code (optimal code with varying length) the expected number of zeros is half the expected length

Tags: huffman-code

I don't really know in which forum to put this question, so any other suggestion will be welcomed.

I saw in some paper that I read that in huffman code (optimal code with varying length) the expected number of zeros is half the expected length.

It seems logical from the way we build the code, but why is it true? I mean, how I can prove it ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description. Also add a link to the paper and quote the exact paragraph you are talking about.

Comment: I am not sure about a formal proof, but intuitively it makes sense: Huffman encoding is about removing redundancy, and, if I recall correctly, has been proven to be a minimal binary representation of the input data based on symbol frequencies. It would be surprising, then, if the output of Huffman encoding didn't contain a balanced number of ones and zeroes, because if the count was lopsided you would be able to capitalize on that knowledge and compress the output further, which contradicts the stated optimality of Huffman.